# remove the textview and button from an activity and pull remaining components up after clicking a button

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which loads in a linear layout from XML file.
What I want is that an additional textview and a button should appear when the application is run. BUT it should never appear again when the user clicks on "bGotIt" button [using the sharedpreferences stuff]

But what I want is that the textview and button must appear at the top of the activity and must push down my permanent components  !! And when the "bGotIt" button is clicked, both these textview and button should disappear and the permanent components must pull themselves up and fill the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/firstTimeText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bla bla bla bla "

            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/bGotIt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Got it !! "
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


              Here I have my permanent components



     </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way, hope this will help you...
Note : i try to put this "Button" and "TextView" in one layout and just try to change layout visibility (Show/Hide) on "bGotIt" "Button" click.

**activity_main** 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrHidable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTimeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bla bla bla bla "/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGotIt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Got it !! "
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            Here I have my permanent components

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

**MyActivity**
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private LinearLayout lnrHidable;
    private Button bGotIt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lnrHidable = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrHidable);
        bGotIt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGotIt);

        // visiable as your sharedpreferences
        bGotIt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        bGotIt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGotIt);
        bGotIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lnrHidable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It is still not working :\ XML file is showing error ......

I can have as many components as I want in relative layout within framelayout........ right ?